# "Double vectorize" Numpy functions across two different arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Is there some efficient way to "double vectorize" a Numpy function?

Consider some function `f` which is vectorized over its first 3 positional arguments; its implementation consists entirely of Numpy vectorized functions (arithmetic, trigonometry, et alia) which correctly implement broadcasting.

The first two arguments of `f` are `x` and `y`, which represent some kind of input data. Its 3rd argument `q` is a parameter that controls some aspect of the computation.

In my program, I have the following:

- Arrays `x` and `y` that are 1-d arrays of the same length. `x[i]` and `y[i]` correspond to the `i`th data point in a dataset.
- Array `q` which is a 1-d array of different length. `q[k]` corresponds to some `k`th data point in a different collection.

I want to compute the value of `f(x[i], y[i], q[k])` for any pair `i, k`, collecting the results in a matrix.

That is, I want to perform a vectorized version of the following calculation:

```py
result = np.empty((len(x), len(q))
for k in range(len(q)):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        result[i, k] = f(x[i], y[i], q[k])
```

The "singly-vectorized" version (over the `i` index) would be:

```py
result = np.empty((len(x), len(q))
for k in range(len(q)):
    result[:, k] = f(x, y, q[k])
```

And this is what I currently use in my code.

Is there an efficient way to vectorize over *both* indexes, maybe using some broadcasting trick?

As an example of such a function `f`, consider the Law of Cosines:

```py
def law_of_cosines(a, b, ϑ):
    return np.sqrt(
        np.square(a) +
        np.square(b) +
        2.0 * a * b * np.cos(ϑ)
    )
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add a closer example to what kind of numpy operation you're looking for, instead of the multiplication example?

Comment: My actual code is a bit complicated. Perhaps it will be less distracting if I rewrite it as `f(x, y, z)` where `f` is some arbitrary ufunc over its 3 paramters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the actual `f`, I think I'd approach it like...

```py
# set up example variables
N, M = 11, 13
x = np.random.normal(N)
y = np.random.normal(N)
q = np.random.normal(M)

# reshape for broadcasting
X = x[:, np.newaxis]
Y = y[:, np.newaxis]
Q = q[np.newaxis, :]

f(X, Y, Q)
```

then if `f` is, I lack the proper term for it, `ufunc`-like, it should broadcast nicely. If it isn't, and it's hard to tell without the actual "a bit complicated" implementation", you could make it so either via changing the implementation or possibly by [`numba`'s `vectorize` decorator](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-vectorize-decorator), which is how I usually do that.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! And yes, I wanted to be clear that in my case `f` is fully vectorized, "`ufunc`-like". For example the Law of Cosines, `def x,y,q: return np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 - 2*x*y*np.cos(q))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorise the second "vectorised" multiplication operation using np.outer. It contains no for loops.

The following code contains a print statement with the "double-vectorised" version. I also fixed the minor typo in brackets in the creation of the empty results matrix.

```
import numpy as np
x = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
y = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
q = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]

result = np.empty((len(x),len(q)))
for k in range(len(q)):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        result[i, k] = np.arctan2(x[i], y[i]) * q[k]
print(result)
print(np.outer(np.arctan2(x, y) , q))
```

Results:

```
[[0.09799147 0.12248933 0.1469872  0.17148506]
 [0.12870022 0.16087528 0.19305033 0.22522539]
 [0.14350827 0.17938534 0.2152624  0.25113947]]
[[0.09799147 0.12248933 0.1469872  0.17148506]
 [0.12870022 0.16087528 0.19305033 0.22522539]
 [0.14350827 0.17938534 0.2152624  0.25113947]]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should have clarified that I wasn't specifically looking for _multiplication_ as the result. The `outer` function in R lets you provide a function other than `*` to use, but it doesn't look like `np.outer` has the same option.

Comment: By the way, instead of printing out and visually grepping for differences, try using `np.testing.assert_allclose` for this kind of comparison!  It's a lovely little function that not enough people know about.